# EF 6 WCF Data Services 5.6 OData Expand Not Working

Tags: entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

I had the unfortunate requirement to downgrade (just the UI, not the WCF Service) from 4.5 to 4.0.  Which meant I could not use (to my understand) the WCF OData Services that I had working like a champ in 4.5.  After the downgrade I had an error and found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2013/10/02/using-wcf-data-services-5-6-0-with-entity-framework-6.aspx) article that got it up and working quickly.

However, it seems that it may not be 100% working.  I have removed Filtering and such to make it as simple as possible.

The following query works:

`http://localhost:51562/BORODataService.svc/StagComplaints`

That will give me all of the StagComplaints in the database.

Other modifiers work:

`http://localhost:51562/BORODataService.svc/StagComplaints?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=5`

This used to work:

`http://localhost:51562/BORODataService.svc/StagComplaints?$filter=UserIdentification eq '913'&$expand=Parcels`

But it no longer does.  There is a Parcels property on the StagComplaint.  I do realize I installed Alpha2 which it just may be something not included yet.  I know the format is correct based on [this](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/#46_Expand_System_Query_Option_expand) article.  But I am also not sure if it is just something I am missing.

Comment: I'm doing some investigation on EF6 provider. In my case, $expand can work by default. In your case, Parcels is a navigation property of StagComplaints? Can you share your metadata?

Comment: @zoe, is this what you were looking for: public partial class StagComplaint : ComplaintBase {
 public IList<StagParcel> Parcels { get; set; }
 public ComplaintType ComplaintType { get; set; }
 public int ComplaintTypeID { get; set; }

 [IgnoreDataMember]
 public virtual Complaint OriginalComplaint { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey("OriginalComplaint")]
 public int? OriginalComplaintID { get; set; }

 public StagComplaint() {
  this.Parcels = new List<StagParcel>();
 }
}

Comment: Actually I want to know the content of http://localhost:51562/BORODataService.svc/$metadata. Can you show me StageComplaint definition in $metadata and the error message of $expand?

Comment: Sorry, that does not work.  I tried a few different ways and can not get it to produce the metadata.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out.  But the file is far to large to paste here.  I can email it to you if you want.

Comment: Please post the $expand error message first, maybe I can get some clue from it, thanks!

Comment: Ouch, that is not going to happen.  I posted this 9+ months ago.  Do not really have the time and I know the back-end servers and configuration has changed to get things to work in that environment.  Sorry and good luck.

Comment: Sorry, since i'm doing some investigation on EF6 provider recently and i saw this question. Never mind, I just try to find out the EF6 provider issues.